# Replacing multiple strings in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, replace

I am trying to replace multiple categorical variables from a dataframe with a set of values.

I tried the following codes:

```
data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].replace(to_replace={"male","M","m","female","f","F"}, value={"Male","Male","Male","Female", "Female", "Female"}).
```

I want every m, M, or male to be replaced by Male. Same for the female category.

I got error:

ValueError: Replacement lists must match in length. Expecting 6 got 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you use `set`s for the arguments of the `replace()` method. The cardinality may be fine for `to_replace`, as all elements are unique. For `value`, the `set` you define actually gets to be `{"Male", "Female"}`, which does not match the cardinality of `to_replace`. Even if the cardinality is matched, `set`s do not guarantee an order, so it is not a suitable data structure for the job at hand. Instead, If you use `list`s or `tuple`s, this would just work:

```
data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].replace(to_replace=("male","M","m","female","f","F"), value=("Male","Male","Male","Female", "Female", "Female")).
```

although using a `dict` may lead to simpler to read code, as the replacements are written close together:

```
data["Gender"] = data["Gender"].replace({"m" : "Male", "M" : "Male", "male": "Male", "f": "Female", "F": "Female", "female": "Female"})
```

Comment: This is spot on. 
Thank you.
I have taken note of your comment for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender': ['m', 'M', 'f', 'F', 'm']})
print(df)
    
  Gender
0      m
1      M
2      f
3      F
4      m

replace_values = {'m' : 'Male', 'M' : 'Male', 'f':'Female','F':'Female'}                                                                                          
df = df.replace({"Gender": replace_values}) 
df

   Gender
0    Male
1    Male
2  Female
3  Female
4    Male
```